# Nautilus doesn't open from desktop sidebar (dock) icon on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: nautilus, 19.04, ubuntu-dock, alienware

I recently installed Ubuntu 19.04 on my Alienware m-17 laptop in dual boot setting with Windows 10. Everything seems to work okay except Nautilus which ***sometimes*** does not launch from the dock icon.
I can launch it from the terminal every time but not from the desktop icon.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Yes, Install Nvidia proprietary drivers. You'll find a recommended one in Additional Drivers.

Comment: If Nautilus (Files) works WITHOUT errors when launched from the terminal, then maybe your dock icon, or desktop icon is not correct. When you say "desktop icon", exactly what do you mean, as there's nothing like this in a standard Ubuntu installation? If when launching from terminal, do you see TWO Files icons in the dock?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia although I have no problem with your suggestion to install Nvidia drivers, per se... how do you figure that OP has Nvidia cards... and how do you think this is related to Nautilus (Files) not working?

Comment: @heynnema Alienware line of gaming laptops have Nvidia cards. And this symptom - unresponsive mouse clicks in the desktop - has been experienced before when running with the `nouveau` driver in same high-end Nvidia cards. Yeah, I know a thing or two... ;)

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia excellent response :-))

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I have already installed proprietary drivers. They were installed automatically with Ubuntu installation.

Comment: @heynnema By desktop icon, I mean dock icon. And no I don't see two icons when launching Nautilus from terminal.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: @heynnema there is no output. I get an error message.
*ls: cannot access '/home/tayyab/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory*

Comment: Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and tell me what extensions you see there.

Comment: Log into another account on the system, and see if `Files` launches consistently there. Create a temporary `guest` or `test` account if required.

Comment: @heynnema I get the following error message 
*We cannot detect a running copy of GNOME on this system, so some parts of the interface may be disabled. See our troubleshooting entry for more information*

Comment: At the login screen, select or type in your username, locate the cogwheel icon, click on it, and tell me what environment is selected. If it's NOT Ubuntu, please select it, finish logging in, and retest.

Comment: @user3155031 So you know, Ubuntu isn't Manjaro. Nvidia drivers are not automatically installed, the open-source `nouveau` is. User can install Nvidia *proprietary* drivers at Software & Updates > Additional Drivers. And even an old Nvidia driver version (older than recommended for your actual card) can have issues. So, please, for your own good, do check that.